# Derive configuration based on web api call in dot net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the configuration in appsettings.json as,

```
"AppConfiguration":{
   "ApiConfig1":{
       "UserId": "User1",
       "Password": "Password1"
    },
"ApiConfig2":{
       "UserId": "User2",
       "Password": "Password2"
    },
```

I use

```
services.Configure<ApiConfig1>
(Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration:ApiConfig1"));
services.Configure<ApiConfig2>
(Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration:ApiConfig2"));
```

I am passing string in webapi as Config1. Could you please tell me based on webapi call how to retrieve ApiConfig1 or ApiConfig2. Moreover I am using this config across all projects so I want one time initiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have fixed the issue with the below steps,

Have a IMemorycache in controller and set the string,

```
_cache.Set("Config", Config1)
```

Create a factory in the startup.cs,

```
services.AddTransient(factory =>
        {
            IOptions<ApiConfig>  Func(string key)
            {
                switch (key.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "Config1":

                        return factory.GetService<IOptions<ApiConfig1>>();
                    case "Config2":

                        return factory.GetService< IOptions<ApiConfig2>>();
                    default:
                        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
                }
            }

            return (Func<string, IOptions<ApiConfig>>)Func;
        });
```

Then wherever I need the config, get the value from cache and initialize the ApiConfig base class,

```
    public MyClass(Func<string, IOptions<ApiConfig>> configoptionsAccessor, IMemoryCache cache)
{
    cache.TryGetValue("Config", out string config);
    _apiConfig = configoptionsAccessor(config).Value;
}
```